# How to make Console in Eclipse show result depending on char?

Tags: java, eclipse, char

So I want my 'm' to be first, and 'z' second written in console (female and male students)

```
public class Ispis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student studije[] = new Student[]{
                (new Student ("Ana", "Maric", "150/321", "ČA", "NBG", 
                        new StudentskiDom ("maric","adresa", 'z'), 'z')),
                (new Student ("Pera", "Peric", "150/331", "SM", "NBG", 
                        new StudentskiDom ("maric","adresa", 'm'), 'm')),
                (new Student ("Bojana", "Nikolic", "150/361", "NS", "NBG", 
                         new StudentskiDom ("maric","adresa", 'z'), 'z')),
                (new Student ("Laza", "Lazic", "150/320", "VA", "NBG", 
                        new StudentskiDom ("maric","adresa", 'm'), 'm'))};
    for (int i=0; i<studije.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(studije[i].ime + " " +  studije[i].prezime + " iz " + studije[i].mestoRodjenja + ".");}
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered sorting the `studije` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//print male students:
for (int i=0; i<studije.length; i++) {
   if(studije.gender == 'm'){ // replace "gender" with your attribute for gender in class Students
       System.out.println(studije[i].ime + " " +  studije[i].prezime + " iz " + studije[i].mestoRodjenja + ".")
   }
}

//print female students:
for (int i=0; i<studije.length; i++) {
   if(studije.gender == 'z'){ // replace "gender" with your attribute for gender in class Students
      System.out.println(studije[i].ime + " " +  studije[i].prezime + " iz " + studije[i].mestoRodjenja + ".")
   }
}
```